# How to get spesific month from Date jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I need to show month by date. for example when I select 31 from date then month will be show (1,3,5,7,8,10,12).
I have create, but the result of month is 1.

here is my HTML

```
<label>Day: </label>
<input list="day" class="birth-day" maxlength="2">
<label>Month: </label>
<input list="month" class="birth-month" maxlength="2" disabled>
```

my Javascript

```
function daysInMonth(day) {
  return new Date(day, 0).getMonth() + 1;
}
$('.birth-day').on('change',function() {
  var daysInSelectedMonth = daysInMonth($('.birth-day').val());
  $('#month').text($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(""));
  for (var i = 1; i <= daysInSelectedMonth; i++) {
    $('#month').append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
  }
})
```

Here is my full code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/4bcxL3tu/41/)
Thank you

Comment: Is your goal just to take date input from user?

Comment: As you currently wrote it, `daysInMonth()` uses the Date constructor overload that accepts the year as the first parameter and the month index as the second.  So what you're doing if you pass it 31 is instantiating January 1st, 1931, and then asking for the month index (0), and adding one to it (getting 1).

Comment: yes, take date from user @Tarreq

Comment: I think you using getMonth(), the wrong way, this accepts full Date argument, and returns the month of it, you just giving it a day ?!!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to take a proper date value from user, there is a much cleaner and consistent ways to do that, a datepicker components are widely used.

You can do :

```
HTML:

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div>Selected Date: <input type="text" id="date_ex"></div>
<div id="date_val"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
  $('#date_ex').datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    // date value now in dateText, show it in date_val DIV
    $('#date_val').text(dateText); 
   }
});
```

Live Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/dLumvn12/

Answer (score 0):

You can use getMonth() method

To get specific month :

If you're still stuck follow the link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Comment: I already use getMonth() in my function. and then looping inside class birth-day